# Http response with @ResponseBody

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have method in controller, which annotate with @ResponseBody and return List. I want to send another one parameter with this list. How can I do it?

```
@RequestMapping(...)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    List<Entity> sendResponse() {
        ...
    return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `POJO`, set the properties and return the same.

```
MyPojo{
   List<Entity> myList;
   Object object;
   :
   :
   :
}


@RequestMapping(...)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    MyPojo sendResponse() {
       MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo ();
       myPojo.setMyList(list);
    return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a JSON model that has what you need: a list and the additional parameter. Then return that model from your method instead of the list.